# Installed Google Tag Manager and added Custom HTML in GTM for Facebook Custom Chat but chat window won't show

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, facebook, google-tag-manager

Magento 1.9.3.

Installed https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-chapagain-googletagmanager.html and it is working properly when viewed source code the GTM tag starts and ends immediately after  tag opens.

I have added Facebook Custom Chat Plugin code as advised https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-facebook-messenger-chat-google-tag-manager/ but the chat window still won't show on my website.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I had forgotten to publish the tag in GTM.